# How do I fix low DPI / bad resolution for external monitor on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, display-resolution

I've seen plenty of threads about this online, and tried every one of them. Nothing worked. I'm desperate.

So I have a viewsonic vg2765 running and a GeForce GT 620 OEM graphics card.

I'm stuck at 1024x768 so 4:3. Everything looks zoomed. Dk what to do.

I've tried cvt 1920x1080 even though I could probably run even higher than that.

Then run xrandr --newmode ..etcc, xrandr -addmode ...etc. Even when I set up the DPI in the .profile file. After I apply the new resolution everything is either zoomed or completely out of the screen. Also, I get this error :

```
$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for 
output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 
1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 
0mm x 0mm
1024x768      76.00*
```

Comment: Do you have multiple monitors or only one external monitor?  What video driver are you using?

Comment: Only one directly connected to my Linux tower through an HDMI cable. I'm using the nvidia-driver-390.

Comment: I've seen a lot of questions about this and the key seems to be `output default` instead of a listed output name like `HDMI-0`.  Don't know how to fix though.